# How to: Event Tracking on Flash embedded video

Tags: asp.net, flash, embedded-video, event-tracking

I have an embedded video on a page of my ASP.NET with C# website. I would like to use google analytics to track events on this video, such as how many times the Play button has been pressed.

This is the code I used to embed the video on the web page:

```
<object width="560" height="340"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/whatever_-M4?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/whatever_-M4?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="340"></embed></object>
```

How can I do event tracking on this video player? The "play" button is embedded in the Flash player... Should I be using a Flash API to do this? If so, which, and how?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout following links

[link One](http://code.google.com/p/ga-youtube-tracker/wiki/HowToTrackEmbeddedYoutubeWithGoogleAnalytics)

[Link Two](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147619)

[link three](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/11/09/video-tracking-google-analytics-introduction/)

EDIT: [Example One](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy) [Example Two For your scenario](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro)

**How Does the Component Work?**

In order to use the Flash tracking component in your environment, you either use the visual tools inside Flash, or you set up the tracking object directly in your code. Regardless of whether you are setting up the component visually or via code, you provide the following elements:

the web property ID—This is also known as the UA number of your tracking code and looks like UA-xxxxx-yy, where the x's and y's are replaced with the numbers that correspond to your account and profile information for the object you are tracking. See Web Property for more information.
the tracking mode—Choose either bridge mode or AS3 mode. This mode determines how your tracking communicates with the Analytics servers and is described in detail below.
the debugging mode—No matter which environment or tracking mode you use, you can turn debugging on to validate and test your tracking.

**Tracking Modes**

Depending upon on how you distribute your Flash content, the Analytics for Flash component communicates to the Analytics servers either by bridging the communication between the Flash content on an existing Analytics tracking installation, or by communicating directly to the Analytics servers. These two modes are called bridge mode and AS3 mode, respectively. Both modes use the same Analytics tracking functionality, and it's easy to switch your Flash application from one mode to the other. In addition to choosing a communication mode for Analytics tracking, you can also use a debug mode to troubleshoot or validate your tracking.

In either mode, allowscriptaccess must equal always in order for campaign tracking to work. This parameter turns on read access to the page's URL and referrer information required by the Flash tracking code. Without allowscriptaccess, the Analytics tracking code degrades gracefully. It still provides most user activity data, but will not confirm to the Google Analytics campaign attribution model.
Bridge Mode

Use this mode if you control both the HTML page and the Flash content. This mode is best if you have already implemented Google Analytics (ga.js) tracking on your website and you want to add tracking to embedded Flash content. The bridge mode simplifies Flash-to-JavaScript communication by providing a unified ActionScript 3 interface to the ga.js code. It provides the connection from the ActionScript 3 calls to the Analytics JavaScript in order to make the tracking work.

The connection to the Google Analytics Tracking Code can be configured through the web property ID parameter in one of two ways:

Most common method. The Google Analytics Tracking Code object already exists on your page with its own name, such as pageTracker. In this case, you provide the full DOM reference to the tracking object. For example, if your object is called pageTracker, you would reference that object in your code as window.pageTracker. For example, the following code snippet illustrates how this would be configured using the Adobe Flex environment with ActionScript 3:

```
tracker = new GATracker( this, "window.pageTracker", "Bridge", false );
```

Alternate method. If you have not created a page tracking object on your page, you can simply pass in your web property ID, and a JavaScript tracking code object will be created for you. With this method, reference to the base ga.js javascript source file is still required on your HTML page. The following code snippet illustrates how this would be configured using the Adobe Flex environment with ActionScript 3:

```
tracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-12345-22", "Bridge", false );
```

In order for bridge mode to function correctly, ExternalInterface.available must be set to true in your ActionScript 3 code. This also means that allowScriptAccess should be set to always in the HTML page that embeds the Flash content. The following example illustrates HTML code configured for bridge mode:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
     id="flex_component" width="800" height="600"
     codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
     <param name="movie" value="flex_component.swf" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
     <embed src="flex_component.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
         width="800" height="600" name="flex_component" align="middle"
         play="true"
         loop="false"
         quality="high"
         allowScriptAccess="always"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
      </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: This looks complicated to learn. How do I practically implement this on my website? I am trying to implement "link three" here, but the info in the link doesn't say how to do it... Thanks KnowledgeSeeker!

Comment: User Following link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy

Comment: I have added example which should help